# How do I force a default gateway change? It seems stuck on 192.168.0.1 in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, troubleshooting

This has me stumped. I am connected to a college network, which requires me to have my MAC registered (Done, windows works fine).

So, when I boot to Ubuntu, I try to access a page in Chromium, and I get an
Error 102(net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED): Unknown error.

Firefox fails too.

Resolve.conf has several servers, all of which I can successfully ping, and I can ping digg.com and google.com using their names.

Also, there is constant network activity, but I can't tell what process/ports are downloading and uploading. (netstat -tupl didn't seem to show anything)

I don't have any network managers installed (for w/e reason).

---

**Update**: I randomly tried to update my system, and it of course failed, but I read the text.

The error states that: failed to fetch package blah blah at IP ADDRESS: 192.168.0.1:80 (connection refused).

Obviously, the ip addr of canonical is not 192... but I don't have a router between me and the internet now (I used dhclient to update my settings) so what is rerouting all my http requests to 192.168.0.1?

Using wicd, setting a static ip, dns, and gateway still results in all http traffic getting redirected to 192.168.0.1:80, using 
ip route show | grep default | awk '{ print $3 }' shows a different ip than 192.168.0.1.

Comment: Please post the output of `ipconfig` and `netstat -rn`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the [route](http://linux.die.net/man/8/route) command.  However, it sounds to me like there is a deeper issue going on with your setup.  What error did Firefox give you?

Also, dhclient has been absorbed into dhcp3-client.  Make sure that the version of dhclient you're using is from that package.

Answer (score 0):

To manually input a default gateway you would run this at the command line:

```
~$ route add -net default gw xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

Though, like someone mentioned above, seems like you're having other problems.  From what I can tell, it sounds like you're being routed through a proxy (configured by the school).  Similar to what you'd see when you connect to a public wifi access point and you're redirected to a webpage to accept terms/agreements before you can move onto to surfing the web.  Did firefox give you a specific error?

Comment: No, there isn't any proxy in the traditional sense here.
What we have is:
1. ISS, which basically blocks all incoming connections unless it's disabled.
2. 1 registered MAC address per person, which involves connecting to the jack and going to start.college.edu and logging in (but I've already done that on the windows partition)


I'm not at the computer right now, I have some work to do elsewhere, but I'll try the route command when I get back.

Comment: And no, I'm pretty sure firefox just gave me the typical could not find a page page; but I'll check again when I get back.